# Billingapi onPurchasesUpdated() is not called

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am using Android's latest billing library. In our activity where i initiated the payment using launchBillingFlow(). I am able to receive the purchase update on onPurchasesUpdated().

But 1 outof 10 times I didnt get the onPurchasesUpdated() callback. But the purchase was success and money was deducted from the customers' account.

What could be the reason? First of all is it ok to implement in this way? I am not listening to the purchases in any other screen because our app is a single device app.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but recently I had a similar problem where `onPurchasesUpdated()` wasn't called for slow bank card payments. As I found out this isn't only me, you can see a related discussion here: https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/254

And there's a bug report at Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146480197

We can hope that with a new Play Store app update this problem will be gone, but for now as a workaround I'm repeatedly (once every 1-2 sec.) call `queryPurchases` and check if my purchase state changed.